# How to open VS 11 solution and csprojects in VS 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to open [sample code](http://www.wintellect.com/downloads/CLR_via_C_,_3rd_Edition_Code_by_Jeffrey_Richter_%28January_20,_2010%29.zip) from book "CLR via C#, 3rd edition, J. Richter" in VS2012. When I open main .sln file or .csproj files I'm just getting blank window. Apparently these samples made in VS 11.00.
Any solution?

Comment: VS11 is VS2012.  What do you see in the solution explorer?

Comment: It's empty. Opening .sln file with notepad I see it begins with 'Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010'

Comment: Format Version 11.0 isn't Visual Studio Version 11.0. Visual Studio 2010 (version 10) uses Format Version 11.0

Comment: ok, understood about versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should be able to open VS 2010 projects without a problem in VS 2012. However, VS 2012 appears to have a problem with the # in the solution file name. Rename "CLR via C#.sln" to "CLR via C.sln", and it opens without a problem.

Comment: Yes, confirm that. Do no include the sharp symbol (#) into the file names of your solutions. VS 2012 definitely has problems with that.